# How to use observer_field in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a single select_tag with categories gathered from array in controller. When the user selects a category I want the application to redirect to the selected category. I have the following code in my view which. (I've tried both using :method => :get and :post, only change is in development.log)

```
<%=select_tag "cat_selected", options_for_select(@cats_for_mt)%><br>
<%=observe_field 'cat_selected',
  :url => {:action => :viewflokkur},
  :with => 'cat',
  :method => :get %>
```

When I select one of the options the following gets logged to development.log.

```
Processing CategoriesController#viewflokkur (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-06-12 12:33:26) [GET]
Parameters: {"cat"=>"Taugasjúkraþjálfun", "authenticity_token"=> "B2u5ULNr7IJ/ta0+hiAMBjmjEtTtc/yMAQQvSxFn2d0="}
Rendering template within layouts/main
Rendering categories/viewflokkur
Completed in 20ms (View: 18, DB: 0) | 200 OK [http://localhost/categories/viewflokkur?cat=Taugasj%C3%BAkra%C3%BEj%C3%A1lfun&authenticity_token=B2u5ULNr7IJ%2Fta0%2BhiAMBjmjEtTtc%2FyMAQQvSxFn2d0%3D]
```

According to this I should now be in "viewflokkur", but nothing changes in the browser window. Is there anything else I need to do, maybe in the controller?

BR,
Sindri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example of Observe field :

```
<label for="search">Search term:</label> 
<%= text_field_tag :search %> 
<%= observe_field(:search, 
              :frequency => 0.5, 
              :update => :results, 
              :url => { :action => :search }) %> 
<div id="results"></div>
```

Found [here](http://blog.nanorails.com/pages/rails-1-1-cheat-sheet).

Comment: I don't really want to update a div-tag within my page, I want it to redirect. Can I do that?

Comment: Thanks though, ended up finding a way similar to your suggestion :)